# Sitecore Commerce Installation Error at GetIdServerToken

Tags: sitecore-commerce, commerce-engine

I am installing sitecore commerce in development environment, encountered some errors prior to this error, all those are fixed, now i am getting this error. seems some issue with the Identity Server. any help would be much appreciated. i can give more details if required.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned you had problems before this with installation, please can you post those here? You can also check the steps below:

1. Check logs in Identity server `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\SitecoreIdentityServer\wwwroot\logs`.
2. Check that connection string points to the correct username and password.
3. Update Trusted connection to False.

Answer (score 0):

Before performing the installation again for the same instance, you need to check the below steps:

1. Ensure that there is no custom `AllowedCorsOriginsGroup` in `<InstallationFolder>\SIF\IdentityServer\Sitecore.Commerce.IdentityServer.Host.xml` (they’re added automatically in prior installations)
   [image]
2. Since you're running the same script again to reinstall the Sitecore XC, You must remove the reference to the "ModuleHabitatImages" from the `Includes` section of the `<InstallationFolder>\SIF\Configuration\Commerce\Master_SingleServer.js` file.

```
## Remove this for second-time installation
"Module-HabitatImages": {
                "Source": ".\\Configuration\\Commerce\\Common\\Common.InstallWdpModule.json"
            },
## you can remove this to fasten up the second time installation
"Module-AdventureWorksImages": {
                "Source": ".\\Configuration\\Commerce\\Common\\Common.InstallWdpModule.json"
            }
## Also, you can remove this to fasten up the second time installation:     
"Module-PowershellExtensions": {
                "Source": ".\\Configuration\\SitecoreUtilities\\InstallModule.json"
            },     
"Module-SXAFramework": {
                "Source": ".\\Configuration\\SitecoreUtilities\\InstallModule.json"
            },
```

3. Do the IIS Reset.

After performing all the above steps, do the installation again.